# OpenCV, DMatch objects in Python and Julia don't match

Tags: python, c++, opencv, julia, feature-detection

I'm trying to implement a feature matching method using OpenCV, but the translation from a Python version to Julia does not match up:

The methods are exactly the same and use the same images for processing. (`[:method]` is just standard convention for accessing a specific type of method in Julia, so don't be fooled! Also, Julia indexing starts at 1, not 0, so these two sets of print statements *should* yield the same result, but they don't.)

**Julia version:**

```
query = cv2.imread("images/q1.jpg",0)
train = cv2.imread("images/q2.jpg",0) 

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1 = orb[:detect](query)
kp1, des1 = orb[:compute](query, kp1)

kp2 = orb[:detect](train)
kp2, des2 = orb[:compute](train, kp2)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf[:knnMatch](des1, des2, k=2)

print(matches[1])
print(matches[1][:distance])
```

prints the below. Only one DMatch object is stored in `matches`.

```
PyObject <DMatch 0x7fac68b2be50>
305.0639343261719
```

**Python version:**

```
query = cv2.imread('images/q1.jpg',0)       
train = cv2.imread('images/q2.jpg',0)

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1 = orb.detect(query)
kp1, des1 = orb.compute(query, kp1)

kp2 = orb.detect(train)
kp2, des2 = orb.compute(train, kp2)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

print(matches[0])
print(matches[0][0].distance)
```

prints the below. Two DMatch objects are stored in `matches`

```
[<DMatch 0x7f0266a47a70>, <DMatch 0x7f0266a47c50>]
305.0639343261719
```

My question is, why is only one DMatch object stored in the `matches` that I created with Julia, but two are stored in the one I created with Python, [**NOTE**: I need both DMatch objects to successfully implement feature matching, so the Python one is correct!] and how can I fix the problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
writing `print(matches)` for both examples gives the following:

In Julia:

```
Any[PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c290f90> PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c290fb0>
    PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c290fd0> PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c2bc030>
…
    PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c24be10> PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c24be30>
    PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c24be50> PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c24be70>]
```

In Python:

`[[<DMatch 0x7fcda37c5730>, <DMatch 0x7fcda37c5830>], [<DMatch 0x7fcda37c5650>, <DMatch 0x7fcda37c5610>],... [<DMatch 0x7fcda375f5d0>, <DMatch 0x7fcda375f5f0>], [<DMatch 0x7fcda375f610>, <DMatch 0x7fcda375f630>]]`

Comment: What happens if you replace `print(matches[1])` with `print(matches)`?

Comment: `print(matches)` in the Julia example gives the following: 
(I also put it in the question)

Julia 
`Any[PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c290f90> PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c290fb0>
    PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c290fd0> PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c2bc030>
…
    PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c24be10> PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c24be30>
    PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c24be50> PyObject <DMatch 0x7ff58c24be70>]`

Comment: Thanks. Answered below.

Comment: @FengyangWang Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCall will convert nested lists in Python to two-dimensional arrays in Julia. For instance,

```
julia> pyeval("[[1, 2], [3, 4]]")
2×2 Array{Any,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

This means that to access the first row, as you tried `matches[1]` for, you need `matches[1,:]`. To access the first element of the first row, try `matches[1,1]`.

When you do `matches[1]`, Julia gives you the first element in matches, which in this case is the first column of the first row.

(Note that when printed, two dimensional arrays are usually aligned and elements are separated by spaces, while one dimensional arrays are not aligned and elements are separated by commas. This is a good way to tell.)